# Flutter firebase_database - DatabaseReference runTransaction - Simultaneous transactions - both goes through

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Did not know how to succinctly title this problem, but here is the problem.

I am making use of firebase_database: ^4.4.0 in my Flutter App.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Linux, locale en_ZA.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at /home/bob/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (10 weeks ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1

  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/bob/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A510F (mobile)       • NOPE             • android-arm   • Android 7.0 (API 24)
    • SM A205F (mobile)       • NOPE2            • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554    • android-x86   • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

In one part of the app, there exists the possibility that 2 users can update the same document at the same time, or more precisely, a 'status' value of a document: `{ 'status' : 'foo' }`.

In order to prevent a possible race condition, Firebase recommends using a Transaction, like so (which is called on a button press):

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('status');

    myRef.keepSynced(true);
    final TransactionResult transactionResult =
        await myRef.runTransaction((MutableData mutableData) async {

      if (mutableData.value == "foo") {
        mutableData.value = "bar";
      } 

      return mutableData;
    });

    if (transactionResult.committed)
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MustOnlyNavigateHereIfStatusUpdated(),
        ),
      );
    else
      Toast.show("Too slow!", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
  }
```

Having 2 devices (with 2 different FireBase users, btw) with the app open and pressing the button at the same time results in BOTH the apps navigating to the next page when only the first one which successfully changed the status should. On the next page, the current user is also added to the document.

Yet, a delay of one second in pressing the buttons results in only the first one going through to the next page, so the code works kinda, but I need only one update to be made so that the first change to the status only navigates to the next page.

Alternatively, I could just check if a user has been added to the document, and if one is already present, stop the second user from continuing, but this feels wrong?

Maybe I am doing it wrong? Any advice will be appreciated.

EDIT: So I tried 'catching' the 2nd user on the navigated page by checking if a user has been added to the document, ie.

```
myRef.child("user").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.value == null) {
            myRef.child('user').set(username);
          }
    }
```

But this is really just moving the race condition over to the next page.